# My gravity simulation gets stuck

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, physics

I am making a gravity simulator to get the feel for physics based coding and I have made an idea here. But I have a problem, after some point after bouncing, the particle (square) gets stuck bouncing to the same point. Does anyone know why?

Heres a link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jjndeokk/6/

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var gravity, objectDensity, force;
gravity = 10.8;

function Object(mass, x, y, w, h, acc, hacc) {
  this.m = mass;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.a = acc;
  this.ha = hacc;
};
var particle = [];
var rows = [1];
for (let i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
  particle.push(new Object(10, i * 30, 10, 20, 20, 0, 0));
};

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
  for (let i = 0, len = particle.length; i < len; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(particle[i].x, particle[i].y, particle[i].w, particle[i].h)
    particle[i].a += gravity;
    particle[i].ha = 3;
    particle[i].x += particle[i].ha;
    if (particle[i].y + particle[i].h + particle[i].a > c.height) {
      particle[i].y = c.height - particle[i].h;
    } else {
      particle[i].y += particle[i].a;
    }
  }
}

function update() {
  for (let i = 0, len = particle.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (particle[i].a >= 0) {
      if (particle[i].y + particle[i].h >= c.height) {
        particle[i].a *= -1;

      }
    }
  }
  draw();
}
setInterval(update, 60);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason your bounce gets stuck is that you are applying gravity to the dot *even when it is on the ground*. After that, you reverse its velocity and it flies back up into the air.

You need to check whether it's on the ground and not apply gravity if it is:

```
if (isAboveFloor(particle)) {
  particle.a += gravity;
}
```

Once that's fixed, what you'll actually find is that the bounce goes back and forth between its initial height and the ground, and this is to be expected - it's conservation of momentum.

In order to make the bounce more realistic, you need to introduce a "coefficient of restitution" that is less than 1:

```
if (particle.y + particle.h >= c.height) {
  particle.a *= -cRest;   // cRest is between 0 and 1
}
```

Once that's done, you get a pretty nice simulation: https://jsfiddle.net/jjndeokk/17/

I've also made the following modifications:

- Used `.forEach` so that the code isn't completely littered with `[i]`s
- Made the gravity and velocity calculations take time into account
- Renamed `particle.a` and `particle.ha` to `particle.vy` and `particle.vx` because those properties were measuring velocity, not acceleration.
- Moved all of the calculations into the `update()` function so you don't have most of them in the `draw()` function.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var gravity, objectDensity, force;
gravity = 240; // pixels / second / second
var cRest = 0.6;

var interval = 60;
var secondsPerInterval = interval / 1000;

function Object(mass, x, y, w, h, vxi, vyi) {
  this.m = mass;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.vx = vxi;
  this.vy = vyi;
};
var particles = [];
var rows = [1];
for (let i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
  particles.push(new Object(10, i * 30, 10, 20, 20, 40, 0));
};

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  particles.forEach(function(particle) {
ctx.fillRect(particle.x, particle.y, particle.w, particle.h);
  })
}

function isAboveFloor(particle) {
  return Math.abs(particle.y + particle.h - c.height) > 1;
}

function update() {
  particles.forEach(function(particle) {
if (particle.vy < 0 || isAboveFloor(particle)) {
  particle.x += particle.vx * secondsPerInterval;
  particle.y = Math.min(particle.y + particle.vy * secondsPerInterval, c.height - particle.h);
  
  // if still above floor, accelerate
  if(isAboveFloor(particle)){
    particle.vy += gravity * secondsPerInterval;
  }
}

if (particle.vy >= 0 && particle.y + particle.h >= c.height) {
  particle.vy *= -cRest;
}
console.log(particle);
  });
  draw();
}
setInterval(update, interval);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That's much more help than I expected. Very helpful.

Comment: I don’t know why you conditionally applied gravity. All you needed was restitution and checking vy instead of a.

Comment: @cdo256 Feel free to provide a fiddle or your own answer if you think there's a better approach. As I stated in my answer, I am conditionally applying gravity because the particle should not be accelerating downward if it is already on the ground. Restitution accounts for the momentum lost in a collision. It doesn't account for an object's inability to accelerate into a surface it is already touching.